# Joining tables based on time and distance: PostGIS with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, spatial, timestamp, postgis, query-performance

I have a table with several thousand rows that contains time and position data. Rows with the same group_id have the same timestamp. Lets call this table "Small":

```
Small Table:
id  event_time                   group_id   item_id  position
1   '2018-06-21 18:35:01.631094+00' '123a'  1   '01010230...'
2   '2018-06-21 18:35:01.630881+00' '123a'  2   '01010044...'
3   '2018-06-18 10:35:01.630663+00' '321b'  1   '01015600...'
4   '2018-06-18 10:35:01.630305+00' '321b'  2   '01010031...'
```

I have another table (Table "Big") that has similar data columns (time, position, data1, data2 etc). The timestamps in this table continuous and are overlapping over the first table and there are 80+ million rows:

```
Big Table:
id  event_time                       Data1   position
1   '2018-06-21 18:45:01.631094+00' 'john'  '01013000...'
2   '2018-06-21 18:41:01.630881+00' 'joe'   '01016000...'
3   '2018-06-21 18:33:01.630663+00' 'john'  '01017000...'
4   '2018-06-21 18:30:01.630305+00' 'rory'  '01018000...'
```

I have geospatial and time indexes on the two tables.

What I would like to do is find the nearest matches between Big and Small and return data1, data2 and the differences in space and time. In short I'd like to find out that "john" is the best match to group '123a', item 2  and he was 100m and 2 minutes from it but 'rory' was closest to item 1 (5 minutes and 1 km or whatever).

I've tried a command similar to this but it is way too slow. It doesn't seem to be using the indexes.

```
SELECT 
  big.id, 
  small.id,
  st_distance(big.position, small.position) as pos_delta,
  (big.event_time, small.event_time) as time_delta,
  big.data1,
  small.item_id
FROM big, small 
WHERE
  (big.event_time - small.event_time) < '2 hours'
ORDER BY login_sar_vessel.position <-> login_pos_report.position
LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to possible first select data from big table for 2 hours around the timestamp associated with the group_id, find the big rows with  the smallest (big.position to small.position) distance and then repeat for each group_id? That seems a bit messy.

Oh, and the DB is postgres 9.6 with postgis 2.4.

Comment: how is rory closer at 1km when john was 100m...

Comment: The positions for item 1 is not the same as the position for item 2. John is close to 2. Rory is closer to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
SELECT
  big.id,
  small.id,
  ST_Distance(big.geom, small.geom),
  big.event_time <-> small.event_time
FROM small
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM big
  WHERE (small.event_time <-> big.event_time) < '2 hours'::interval
  ORDER BY small.geom <-> big.geom
  OFFSET 0
  LIMIT 1
) AS big;
```

You can put both of these on both timestmap and your geom for extra joy using [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/btree-gist.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

CREATE INDEX ON big USING gist (event_time, geom);
CREATE INDEX ON small USING gist (event_time, geom);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE big;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE small;
```

Note: I would upgrade to PostgreSQL 10 so you'd have parallel stuff, as it'll make a **major** difference for this work load.

You may also consider BRIN indexes on the timestamp, and clustering by timestamp. And after that's done going to GIS. Or even creating a new indexed `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with only the last week of data or whatever.

Comment: I get an error using <-> on the timstamps: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone <-> timestamp with time zone

Comment: @RedM try running `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`

Comment: okay that's working now but I get the same error on the next operator: ERROR: operator does not exist: "geometry <=> geometry"

Comment: @RedM supposed to be `<->`. fixed.

Comment: @RedM ? working?

Comment: yeah, it's running now. It's a pig of a table so it's taking some time. I'm going to limit it to one group_id and to get an idea on performance.

Comment: When I add "where small.group_id = '123a' AND (small.event... " to the inside of the join sub query it returns 0 rows. Any ideas how to limit this to just a single group_id correctly?

Comment: I would put that condition on the outer, but it shouldn't return 0 queries on the inner either.

Comment: Ah, mistake was between keyboard and chair. Used the wrong group_id. Returning 0 rows is correct. I think I can speed up the query even more by limiting the positions from Big table to the bounding box of the group_id from small table

Comment: @RedM what was the speed up?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, I tried to build the gist time index on the dev machine but ran out of space. I'm dumping the dev machine's tables to a bigger server and will build the index and try again today.

Comment: @RedM How did things go with the gist time index? I have a similar problem, but with two big-ish time series tables (~40m rows), joining on time and ordering on geography.

Comment: I ended up doing something else using 3 common table expressions. The first to get all points in the "small" table that by group, the next to return "big" data + - 1 hour and within bounds of the small group ID. I'll stick it up here tomorrow when I'm in the office.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the option that I ended up using. It uses a couple common table expressions to cut the data down to the minimum amount needed. The idea being to fetch some "Big" data from before and some from after the "Small" timestamp. Then to sort and find the closest "Big" point, in time and space, to the "Small" point. It needs some work:

```
--Get Small info
WITH small_cut AS
(SELECT * FROM
small 
WHERE
group_id = 'abc123'
),

-- Get BIG info from before Small event 
big_before as
(SELECT DISTINCT ON (Data1)
big.data1
big.position,
big.event_time, 
(small_cut.event_time - big.event_time) as time_delta,
FROM
big,small_cut
WHERE
ST_Within(big.position, small_cut.bounding_geom)
AND
big.event_time > small_cut.event_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 Hours'  
AND
big.event_time < small_cut.event_timestamp
ORDER BY data1, big.event_time DESC
),

big_after as
(SELECT DISTINCT ON (Data1)
big.data1
big.position,
big.event_time, 
(small_cut.event_time - big.event_time) as time_delta,
FROM
big,small_cut
WHERE
ST_Within(big.position, small_cut.bounding_geom)
AND
big.event_time > small_cut.event_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 Hours'  
AND
big.event_time < small_cut.event_timestamp
ORDER BY data1, big.event_time DESC
)

SELECT DISTINCT ON (small.item_id)
* 
FROM Big, small_cut, big_before, big_after
WHERE
{some Id's are equal to other's}
```

I'm not sure how useful this is to other people since my DB structure has changed a bit and isn't 100% inline with the dummy data I've provided.